# Exit function in C++ with return statement

Tags: c++, function, menu, return, submenu

When we have functions, the `return` statement allows us to prematurely exit from the function. Even for a function with no return type, we can use `return` to exit the current function.

**My question is**: Is it a good coding practice to use `return` to exit from the function to go back to the point where the function is called?

One good example of such scenario is a main menu with sub menu.

**Example:**

```
//Decalration
void mainMenu(); 
void subMenu(); 

int main()
{
    mainMenu();
    return 0;
}

//Definition
void mainMenu();
{
    //some codes
    subMenu();
}

void subMenu();
{
    int option;
    cout << "Choose 1 to return to main menu" << endl;
    cout << "Choose 2 to do whatever..." << endl;
    cin >> option;
    if (option == 1)
        return;    //Return to main menu (<--- Is this a good coding practice?)
    else
        //some codes
}
```

**Note:** I am not asking for help in assignment. This is a working code, I just want to know whether using return statement to go back to the point of calling a correct practice? If not, what should be the correct way to return to the point of calling.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @P0W wait..don't down vote my question first.. maybe I should rephrase it?

Comment: Multi-dup, so close vote.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP could not be bothered to look at the thousands of similar questions.

Comment: @user3437460 I didn't down-vote, but clearly you didn't show any search efforts

Comment: I did downvote, and close-vote.

Comment: @P0W Actually I did alot of searching in SO and online regarding the usage of `return` statement already. My question is just like asking whether it is alright to use `return` merely to exit a function. I showed the code as an example, I am not asking for code review. Hope you guys understand :)

Comment: @MartinJames I did alot of research, there are many similar questions, but none talk about the pros and cons of using `return` to end a function.

Comment: @P0W This question is not on-topic for CR.  It's sample code (which is off-topic) and is a best-practice question (which isn't entirely off-topic, but tends to be, particularly when worded as such).

Comment: Returning early is generally good practice in C++. C++ supports multiple exits naturally in the language, so when having multiple exits makes your code clearer, you should use them.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for your reply. I would have accepted your answer if this is not on hold :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++ are different in this regard.

In C, early returns can easily cause cleanup (or even critical business code) to not be performed, especially after the code has been maintained for some time.

In C++ one has to code with the possibility of early exits always in mind, due to the use of exceptions. And so multiple returns are not problematic in good C++ code. Cleanup is performed automatically by destructors, C++ "RAII".

---

From there, it's a matter of personal preference, project coding guidelines, etc.

---

Regarding your code example,

```
void subMenu();
{
    int option;
    cout << "Choose 1 to return to main menu" << endl;
    cout << "Choose 2 to do whatever..." << endl;
    cin >> option;
    if (option == 1)
        return;    //Return to main menu (<--- Is this a good coding practice?)
    else
        //some codes
}
```

one alternative is simply

```
void subMenu();
{
    int option;
    cout << "Choose 1 to return to main menu" << endl;
    cout << "Choose 2 to do whatever..." << endl;
    cin >> option;
    if (option != 1)
    {
        //some codes
    }
}
```

which causes the “exit modal context” to be more manifestly treated specially, but it was already treated specially.

Comment: So can I safely assume using `return` to get back to main menu (for example) has no bad consequences?

Comment: @user3437460: you can and IMHO should assume that, but as anything else it's unsafe. ;-) it's a good assumption because it forces use of C++ style automatic cleanup instead of C style manual explicit cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you are saying that it is good and correct to use `return` to exit from sub-menu? Not sure whether I still can accept your answer when this is on hold.

Comment: "Good" is a value judgement of general practice, where it's generally not a good idea to rely on the authority on just any person who answers a question on SO. "Correct" depends on the context, but as mentioned, with ordinarily good C++ code multiple returns are not problem in the sense of causing bugs, as opposed to the situation in C. Early returns and generally multiple returns are common practice in C++. Some terms for googling (I haven't tested but try it anyway): SESE (single-entry-single-exit) and SEME (single-entry-multiple-exits).